# Как сделать второй язык для сайта без программирования

Tags: html

Хочу добавить английский вариант сайта.

Первая мысль — надо создать дубликат моего индексного файла и перевести там текст на английский. Затем добавить в исходную копию ссылку на вторую страницу в виде, к примеру, флага Великобритании.

Или лучше и правильнее организовать это как-то иначе?

Comment: Можно, но это будет вариант лишь для одной страницы соответственно, а не для всего сайта.

Comment: А у меня лендинг, одностраничный

Comment: Тогда да, этого достаточно.